# If $I\subseteq\mathbb R$ is an interval and $E$ is a topological space, what's meant if $f:I\to E$ is said to admit left-sided limits?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, continuity

Let

- $I\subseteq\mathbb R$ be an interval with $|I|>1$
- $(E,\tau)$ be a topological space
- $f:I\to E$

> How is the notion of admitting a left-sided limit at $t\in I$ defined in this case for $f$?

I guess it should be something like $$\exists\ell\in E:\forall N\subseteq E:(\exists O\in\tau:\ell\in O\subseteq N)\Rightarrow\exists\delta>0:f((t,t+\delta))\subseteq N\tag1\;.$$ I'm just asking cause I'm unsure how the usual case $E=\mathbb R$ needs to be generalized. Is $(1)$ the usually used definition?

Moreover, I've read in a book (where the case $E=\mathbb R$ is considered) a remark saying that in this book "existence of limits means that the function has *finite* limits". What's meant by this remark? I guess it's meant that $\ell\in E=\mathbb R$ and not $\ell\in\overline{\mathbb R}=[-\infty,\infty]$. Is that what is meant? And if so, is this an issue for a general topological space $E$?

Comment: As to the last paragraph, yes, that's what it means.  This doesn't arise for general $E$ (unless you specifically want to embed $E$ in some compactification).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can formulate left-sided limits in terms of sequences: $b$ is a left-sided limit of $f$ at $x$ iff
$$x_n \nearrow x\quad \Longrightarrow \quad f(x_n) \to b$$
(As was pointed out in a comment, for non-Hausdorff E this limit needn't be unique)

The question is whether or not this definition should to be modified to cover the case $f: I \to E$ where $E$ is a general topological space. The answer is 'no': Continuity can be characterized by means of sequences (rater than nets) whenever the domain of $f$ is a first-countable space, e.g. a metric space, but it is independent of the topology of $E$.

Comment: You've defined *left continuity*.  For admitting a left limit, one would ask that there exists $b$ such that for all sequences $x_n \uparrow x$, we have $f(x_n) \to b$, where $b$ does not necessarily equal $f(x)$.  Note also that in a non-Hausdorff space $E$, such $b$ need not be unique if it exists.

Comment: You're right, there is no need for a special modification. However, I guess you agree that your definition boils down to $(1)$, right?

Comment: @NateEldredge For functions between topological spaces, there is a difference between sequential continuity and continuity. Is this an issue here?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: That's exactly the point which Jakob makes in the last paragraph.  Since $I$ is first countable, any sequentially continuous function from $I$ into any topological space $E$ is continuous.  So in fact there is no difference between the two concepts when the domain is $I$.